# Duplicate Surnames in SQL Table

Tags: t-sql

I would like to be able to have a function that  removes duplicate surnames from a name field in a client table- e.g. `'Dummy Dummy Dummy' becomes 'Dummy Dummy'.`

I have googled something for this and can't find anything that does what I want to do above.

Can  you help?

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: Can you edit the question & add some more sample data & desired result ?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Examples are:

Mr Jake Carter Carter
Mr John William Smith Smith
Mr Jane Doe Doe

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data suggests me to use `row_number()` :

```
delete c
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by (select null)) as seq
      from client c
     ) c
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: The values are all in one column, they are not split into different rows.

Comment: MEdwin is correct - it is in one column. Examples values are: Mr Jake Carter Carter Mr John William Smith Smith Mr Jane Doe Doe